Female detective TV show on HBO or Showtime between 2007 and 2008
Can anybody identify this TV show about a female detective that aired on HBO or Showtime between 2007 and 2008?
Female  detective, sex addict, drinks heavily. An angel appears  to her, it is her guardian Angel. She is resistant to help from him.  The show is a lot about their developing relationship. The show takes place in Oklahoma  City, Oklahoma. Her sister was killed in the Oklahoma City bombing. The detective is killed in the final episode in an act of heroism.

This show is Saving Grace with Holly Hunter, and it was not on HBO or Showtime, but on TNT - Turner Network TV.
From the wikipedia article: 

It is set in Oklahoma City — including numerous shots of local
  buildings and landmarks (such as the Oklahoma City National Memorial
  and the downtown skyline) — while much of the show was filmed in
  Vancouver and Los Angeles.
The running theme of the series: In the series opener, Grace meets
  up with her "last-chance" angel, when after a night of drinking she
  runs down and kills a pedestrian with her Porsche. In desperation she
  calls out for God's help, and a scruffy, tobacco-spitting man who
  calls himself Earl (Rippy) appears. Unfolding his wings to reveal his
  divine origins, Earl tells her that she's headed for Hell, and asks if
  she's ready to turn her life over to God.

